# Getting error while fetching request and accessing username from using jwt

Tags: node.js, reactjs, jwt, access-token, mern

This is a validateToken function in JWT.js which is exported to index.js

```
const validateToken = (req, res, next) => {
  const accessToken = req.cookies["access-token"];

  if (!accessToken) {
    res.status(400).json({ error: "You are not authenticated" });
  } else {
    verify(accessToken, secret, (err, decodedToken) => {
      if (err) {
        return res.json({ auth: false, message: "Failed to authenticate" });
      } else {
        const { username } = decodedToken;
        req.username = username; // Assign username to the request object
        next();
      }
    });
  }
};
```

this is an endpoint in index.js

```
app.get('/profile', validateToken, (req, res) => {
  // The user is authenticated and the request includes the username
  const { username } = req;
  res.json({ username });
});
```

this is an request to the server from client side

```
 useEffect(()=>{
    axios.get('http://localhost:5000/profile')
    .then((resp)=>{
      setUsername(resp.data.username);
        setStatus('LoggedIn');
    })
    .catch((err)=>{
      console.log("Error",err)
      setStatus('LoggedOut');
    })
  },)
```

The Error is, I am getting the correct data when I use tools like thunder client to test the request
as shown in image (https://i.stack.imgur.com/aTeuY.png)
but I am getting error when the same request is requested by client on local server or deployed website
as shown in image(https://i.stack.imgur.com/NR3Md.png)(https://i.stack.imgur.com/tGYRa.png)

I want to get the username from the request just like I got using thunder client